# Convert checked values to c# int array in jquery..mvc view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
@model project.models.viewmodel
```

In viewmodel I have a properties,

```
public string name{get;set;} 
public int[] ids{get;set;}
```

Checking these checkboxes happening in an overlay view..and capturing these checked values into searchIDs works..all I need is now to assign these values to model property.

```
<script>
$("#merge_button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchIDs = $("#find-table input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get(); // <----
    console.log(searchIDs);
});
</script>

<form>
 <input name="@model.name">
</form>
```

Can I convert searchIDs into model int[] ids and submit to form ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1:**

```
var ids = new Array();

$.each($("input[name='find-table']:checked"), function() {

    ids.push($(this).val());

});
```

**Example 2:**

```
var ids = $('input:checkbox:checked.find-table').map(function() {
  
  return this.value;
  
}).get();

["1", "2", "3"]
```

In the name of the attribute put your input name, i think your checkbox name is `find-table`.

Comment: shouldn't example 1 have "ids" instead of "values" before .push